# Cannot push Mercurial repo to Bitbucket after committing to default

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I made the mistake of committing to default on my Bitbucket-hosted Mercurial repository. Now, I can no longer push any changes even if they are on another branch. I get an error:

```
permission denied to update branch default
```

I've even tried pushing only a specific branch using `hg push -b BranchName`, but the permission error on `default` is a show-stopper even when I'm not trying to push to that branch. How can I fix this so that I'm able to push changes on two other branches?

Comment: What do you mean by "committing to default on Bitbucket"? Do you mean commit on your repo on default and pushed? Have you tried `hg pull` before pushing?

Comment: @Vince You're right. I committed to default on my local repo and attempted to push. I have tried `hg pull` and get no changes.

Comment: Try `hg outgoing`, and carefully analyze the changesets you are attempting to push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [MqExtension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension) and import the changeset that is in the way as a patch:

```
hg qimport -r tip
```

I'd then check to see if that fixes the issue (you shouldn't need to pop it, but I might be wrong).

As an added bonus (assuming you want to keep the work in that changeset) you could then apply it to one of the branches you *can* push:

```
hg qpop -a
hg up -r BranchName
hg qpush
```

Though you may need to manage some conflicts if the branches differ on those files.

(Additionally, you could try stripping the change if you don't care about keeping it. Or just reclone the repo and only pull over the new work on the named branches.)

Comment: That gives me `abort: cannot import merge revision 394`.

Comment: Did you merge your named branch into default? If so, I think you'll need to strip that one out of the history. Though I am still confused why bitbucket won't let you push to other branches.